# Total reputation difference between SO and stack exchange

Tags: discussion, reputation, questions

Why doesn't the total reputation on stack exchange necessarily match that of stackoverflow? For example, right now, I have 3009 on SO, but 2990 on stack exchange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stack Exchange reputation is just cached, now you can see it 3009 on both.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yeah, but my question was, why wasn't it like that at the moment I asked this question?

Comment: @sawa, hum, answer is because of the **cache** when you see that time. You can ask for feature-request to remove the cache on the another new question, if you don't like that.

Comment: I reloaded the stack exchange page several time, but it didn't help at that time.

Comment: @sawa, its not your browser cache, its the cache inside the system.

Comment: Actually, this page http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/quarter/stackoverflow/2011-04-01/314166#314166 still shows 2990.

Comment: @sawa, thats a league, more caching there, could be need to wait a day or more

Comment: So it just takes time? I can live with it, but how come it's that slow?

Comment: @sawa, yeah ....